# fetch content from webpage and show it in TextView

Tags: android, html, inputstream

I want to update user with some information regarding something. i thought i would fetch some information from the webpage and show it in `TextView`. I have written some code but it is currently giving output like this in `TextView`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is the test message for our user.
</body>
</html>
```

But i want that the message should contains just this line, nothing else.

`This is the test message for our user.`

The code that i have written is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btnSkipContinue;
private TextView txtMessage;
private StringBuilder response;
private String text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSkipContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkipCon);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsgForUsers);
    btnSkipContinue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL("http://mywebiste.com/msg/MsgForUsers.html").openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
        response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        text = response.toString();
        Log.i("Output", text);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    txtMessage.setText(text);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)..

```
String htmlString = "<html><head></head><body>This is the test message for our user.</body></html>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```